# Cannot delete device /dev/loop0

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount

I unsafely removed a USB device that was attached to loop0 with `losetup` and could not delete nor detach loop0 afterwards.

`losetup -a` shows `/dev/loop0: [0005]:145606719 (/dev/sdb1)`

When I remount the device to /dev/sdb1, `umount` it and try `losetup -d /dev/loop0`, I will still get the same error `loop: can't delete device /dev/loop0: Device or resource busy`. Is there a way to get rid of the loop device?

Comment: That's odd, you don't usually attach loop to usb devices. How did you do that?

Comment: I was using LUKS encryption and thought I could encrypt my 1gb usb flash drive.

Comment: You can use LUKS for that, but not by using loop device. A LUKS partition has its own partition type.

Comment: Sorry noobness on my part, cannot find any clear instructions online.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Are you sure that the device isn't busy? Have you ever tried fuser to determine an possible PID?

Precautionary get all possible information:

```
fuser -c /dev/loop0
fuser -d /dev/loop0
fuser -f /dev/loop0
```

Try to stop the process, which could use /dev/loop0. If necessary use `kill -9` or try `fuser -k` to send the kill signal -> look at `man fuser`.

Comment: What is `fuser -d` or `fuser -f` ?
My fuser does not have those flags (`fuser (PSmisc) 22.20`  - from Centos 7.6)

Answer (score 58):

You may have to also use `dmsetup` to remove the device mapping.  Easiest way, if it doesn't interfere with any other mappings is to use a `dmsetup remove_all`.

Comment: This worked for me, though I used `dmsetup info` to get the mappings, then used `dmsetup remove <device>`.  Thank you.

Comment: `sudo dmsetup info` gives me `No devices found`

Comment: This also worked for me. For some reason using kpartx -a and then kpartx -d on CentOS 6.5 doesn't remove the mappings like it should.

Comment: it saves the day if you remove loop dev just by simple `rm /dev/loop` without proper `losetup -d` remove before that.

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar issue with an SD card and Aaoron Flin's suggestion to use dmsetup worked for me.

Specifically, you should be able to `ls` /dev/mapper to see if any `loop0pX` partitions exist.

If so, you can use `dmsetup remove /dev/mapper/loop0p2` to get rid of any unnecessary partitions. This can be useful if you want to keep some mappings attached.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue today and none of the previous answers fixed it (I didn't try to reload the loop kernel module, because I wanted to understand the actual issue).

It turns out the image file associated with the loop device contained an "Linux LVM" partition, which was automatically set as shown by `pvscan`:

```
$ pvscan
  PV /dev/sda1    VG server-vg   lvm2 [417,76 GiB / 0  free]
  PV /dev/loop0   VG vbox-vg     lvm2 [7,81 GiB / 0    free]
  Total: 2 [425,57 GiB] / in use: 2 [425,57 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
```

So I had de deactivate all the logical volumes inside the volume group:

```
$ vgchange --activate n vbox-vg
  0 logical volume(s) in volume group "vbox-vg" now active
```

Eventually I was able to nicely detach the loop device:

```
$ losetup -d /dev/loop0
$ losetup -a
```

Answer (score 7):

I chased this loop solution to the end of the Internet and found the solution is uninstall **snapd** and **purge all associated** files: (In my case this was 167 Gb)

```
sudo apt purge snapd
```

Comment: I purged snapd and the loop device is still. Device: /dev/loop1 (read-only) Contents: Unknown (squashfs 4.0). It happened after I installed Clementine software. I uninstalled the software and this loop device came up. It also says Backing File: /var/lib/snapd/snaps/clementine_274.snap (deleted)

Comment: This causes all software installed through snapd to be removed.

Answer (score 5):

Run

```
mount | grep /dev/loopN
```

to check if the loop device is being mounted somewhere,
then run

```
umount /dev/loopN
```

to unmount it.

If still have problem, then run

```
lsof | grep loopN
```

to check which process is using it then kill it.

Answer (score 3):

Try reloading the loop kernel module. If it does not help then reboot.

Comment: This actually worked for me (other solutions didn't)

Comment: For those who aren't sure how to do this: `modprobe -r loop && modprobe loop`. :)

Comment: modprobe loop is working perfectly if no loop device file is mounted or configured with crypto

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Luks, you need to luksClose first

```
cryptsetup luksClose $whatever
losetup -D
```

Answer (score 2):

THX for this article BiX and all:
I'm not a Linux administrator only a user but can contribute so much to a had loop device problem:

**When a virtual mounted image file (.iso) is not really cleanly removed from the file explorer (Dolphin/Nautilus).**

You can unmount this virtual partition using the Prg "Disks" (under Service Prg's the disk management tool). 
However, the ISO file will still remain as a loop in the device management list. For example, if you want to delete this ISO file reel from the disk, the deletion process will only take place virtually, and the corresponding storage space in MB or GB will not be free at all. The ISO file is no longer visible in Dolphin/Nautilus after the deletion, but the corresponding storage space requirement is not specified as free again; i.e. the information of the free and occupied storage space on the data carrier where this ISO file was is unchanged before and after the deletion.

A simple but unconventional solution is to reboot/start the computer.
But that can‘t not be the real solution!

The Linux shell `losetup`, which is described in the man page, provides a remedy here:

> *losetup is used to associate loop devices with regular files or block devices, to detach loop devices and to query the status of a loop device. If only the loopdev argument is given, the status of the corresponding loop device is shown.*

So you can use `losetup -d /dev/loop0` to delete a file associated with a loop on dev/loop0(! "losetup -d" is just usable as admin., so you need to type `sudo losetup -d` or wath the most LinuxGurus not fink fin, u have a so-terminal static open).

In the man page of `losetup` you can see that the expression `Delete` is not used here, but `Solve`. Nevertheless, according to my example, that a "file is not deleted reel, despite clean unmount" after using the option -d, the file is only now deleted reel. (I'm not a Linux administrator but:) This is rather associated with an assignment of the loopNumber which is virtual, but becomes a real condition when mounting the iso-image (image).

Here the complete syntax to the shell `losetup`:

https://linux.die.net/man/8/losetup

(I work on a bit corrupted linuxMint-18)

Translated from German with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Answer (score 0):

Definitely there is a process using it. If you couldn't determine which process is preventing it from deleting, then restart your server if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Same as by @frntn.

Loops were occupied by RAID:

```
# cat /proc/mdstat

Personalities : [raid0]

md126 : active raid0 loop6p5[1] loop5p3[0]
  209584128 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks

md127 : active raid0 loop6p2[1] loop5p2[0]
  31440896 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks
```

I removed them and everything obeys the orders again.

Answer (score -5):

I just right click the loop device in dolphin and unmount it.